# I can't seem to get PDFbox-3.0.0.jar in my classpath library to import to my main.java

Tags: eclipse, javafx, pdfbox

My issue is that I get an error importing two commands as you see below. I've tried creating it as a new library in module path and then only adding it as external jars. still does not see pdfbox jar in the project.

1. Am I structuring my Library Wrong?
2. Am I importing them wrong?

See error here:

[image]

I have my JavaBuildPath Libraries is structured like this:

[image]

[image]

Am I making a stupid error? I can't find any documentation showing any other way of adding pdfbox.jar in. I found a video of someone adding other jars but it seems to be the same way I'm adding pdfbox into my javabuildpath

I've restructured my project a couple of times trying to get this to fix my invalid import. I made a library and just put the new library inside modulepath, then tried class path. eventually what I have now is what you see above where I've just added external Jars directly into classpath. I'm also aware that I have multiple jars here, I just added them in because I'm not sure specifically what I need

Comment: module path and classpath are different things. Your images show that required libraries on the classpath, not the module path.  Even if jars are on the module path they may not work as modules if they weren't built to do so and you will need to require at least some of them as automatic modules if that is what they are.  If you want something on the classpath, there isn't much reason to have a module-info (you can delete it and create a non-modular app following the instructions for non-modular apps at openjfx.io).

Comment: I don't know about modules, but for ordinary pdfbox work you only need pdfbox and fontbox, not xmp, not the apps, not preflight.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

I would advice you to create a non-modular-project of JavaFX, without module-info.java. Then all of this errors will be gone.

If you really want to use modules, then please create a modular project with Gradle-modules... IMO Java has really great features but its own module-system is really bad implemented.

**Solution 1:**

You can use this software to create a preconfigured non modular application: wedasoft.com/projects/javafx-project-generator

**Solution 2:**

Use one of the following predefined templates. Just download and modify it to your needs:

**Example working JavaFX application with gradle**
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

**Example working JavaFX application with maven**
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular